# Secure Link IP Bypass

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to use the nginx secure link module, but allow myself to bypass hash checking on local IP's.
I'm not sure how to go about it, this is what i have so far:

```
    location /secured/ {
        secure_link $arg_st,$arg_e;
        secure_link_md5 <redacted>$uri$arg_e$remote_addr;
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        alias /srv/http/jmsdirectory/public_html/media/secured/;

        if ($secure_link = "0") {
            rewrite . /media/expired.html last;
        }
        if ($secure_link = "") {
            rewrite . /media/bad_hash.html last;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Define "local IPs".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a configuration like the following may do the trick:

```
# Define your local ip blocks here
geo $local_client {
  default 0;
  127.0.0.1/32 1;
  10.0.0.0/8 1;
}

# This map allows uses the $local_client geo variable above
# to always allow local clients, and passes through $secure_link
# for remote clients.
map $local_client $client_allowed {
  0 $secure_link;
  1 1;
}

server {
  location /secured/ {
    secure_link $arg_st,$arg_e;
    secure_link_md5 <redacted>$uri$arg_e$remote_addr;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    alias /srv/http/jmsdirectory/public_html/media/secured/;

    # $client_allowed is now a drop-in replacement for $secure_link
    if ($client_allowed = "0") {
      rewrite . /media/expired.html last;
    }

    if ($client_allowed = "") {
      rewrite . /media/bad_hash.html last;
    }
  }
}
```